# Socket.io browser client not receiving emit events from socket.io client

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, socket.io

IOS CLIENT WITH SOCKET.IO SWIFT:

```
class SignupViewController: UIViewController{

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000")!)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func createUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    LoginUser(email: emailInput.text!, password: passwordInput.text!){ results in
        self.addHandlers()
        self.socket.connect()
    }
}

private func addHandlers(){
    socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
        self.socket.emit("new-device-connect", "ascascasc")
    }
}
```

SERVER:

```
// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module)
app.io = require('socket.io')(app.start());
//app.start();
app.io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("client connected");  

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

BROWSER CLIENT

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on("new-device-connect", function(d){
        console.log("a new client is connected");   
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", function(){

    });
});
```

When I emit an event in my IOS client name `new-device-connect`, I need the event to be called on my browser client to show a new IOS device connected, but the browser client isn't receiving the `new-device-connect` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a socket.on("new-device-connect") on your server,  I have not done mobile development but I think you are passing that information to your server and not the browser client.  Socket.io should then emit your call to the browser correctly.

Comment: Thanks bro. I can rest easy tonight and smoke a blunt now. I knew I was missing something. I thought if I emit an event from the client that the server and client will both listen for that event since they're on the same socket and port.